# Rendering nested objects in react

Tags: reactjs, object

I am stuck in a task that I thought it was fairly easy but apparently I need more practice working with objects.

So I am trying to display the values that I receive, either inputs or dropdowns depending on how the data is presented.
To understand more I will place here an example of the object structure:

```
    {
        id: 33,
        name: 'Test user',
        type: 'affiliate',
        approved_url: {
            method: '',
            url_template: '',
            body_template: '',
            headers: '',
        },
        created_url: {
            method: '',
            url_template: '',
            body_template: '',
            headers: '',
        },        
        rejected_url: {
            method: '',
            url_template: '',
            body_template: '',
            headers: '',
        },
        tracking_group: 1,
        tracking_source: {
            id: 1,
            name: '',
            created_at: '',
        },
        created_at: '',
    },
```

My concern here is if the approach I am following is acceptable:
What I did so far is:

1. Take the entries of the parent object (excluding the nested ones) and pass the key/values as input fields like this:

```
                    {Object.entries(obj)
                        .filter(([key, value]) => typeof value !== 'object')
                        .map(([key, value]) => {
                            return (
                                <Fragment key={key}>
                                    <Text>{key}</Text>
                                    <Input
                                        name={key}
                                        defaultValue={value}
                                        onChange={e => setData({ ...data[key]:e.target.value })}
                                    />
                                </Fragment>
                            );
                        })}
```

2. At this point I already feel its a bit weird what I did in point 1 but now I think I would render three accordions, one for each state "created, approved, rejected".

Started with something like this:

```
                    {Object.entries(obj)
                        .filter(([key, value]) => typeof value === 'object' && keys.includes(key))
                        .map(([key, value]) => {
                            return (
                                <Fragment key={key}>
                                    <Text>{key}</Text>
                                    <Input
                                        name={key}
                                        defaultValue={value}
                                        onChange={e => setData({ ...data, [key]: e.target.value })}
                                    />
                                </Fragment>
                            );
                        })}
```

and keys is as you could imagine "created, rejected, approved" (because there is one object more that I dont want to manipulate here)

What do you think I could do better? to me this is getting a bit spaghetti and I would like to have ideas of how to make it easier.

Comment: What are `keys` in your second example? What's the desired result?

Comment: I don't think there's much wrong with this. You could flip it round I suppose and simply specify the fields you're interested in rendering, assuming they're unlikely to change. That would simplify things. `['approved_url', 'created_url', 'rejected_url'].map(field => obj.find(field))`. Suspect this will get closed however as being primarily opinion based.